How to clean up shot with Photoshop+Davinci Resolve?
I heard about method of clean up in Davinci Resolve, not by masks or fushion, but by exporting frames as stills, cleaning in Photoshop and importing again to Davinci Resolve.
How can i do that, if my footages is .mov with Red Color gamma(it's for color grading).
When im trying to import cleaned stills to Davinci Resolve again, colors not matching
What format i need when exporting still from Davinci?
What format i need whem exporting cleaned still from Photoshop?
How to import cleaned still again to Davinci Resolve?
